# max(length(col)) How do I apply it to all columns? in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I can check one column using `max(length(col))`.
How do I apply it to all columns without typing?

The purpose is to modify the maximum length allowed for table char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the maximum length of all columns by using [PROCEDURE ANALYSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html) in MySQL 5.7.

Unfortunately, this feature has been removed in MySQL 8.0. So if you use the current version of MySQL you will have to do the typing.